# Limit points of rationals in $R$

Tags: real-analysis

Some background:
I was going through the [lecture 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebnoxgp8mLM&t=2843s) of real analysis series of Harvey Mudd college. The lecture discusses open balls, neighbourhoods,limit points, isolated points and interior points. Till this lecture the series has covered construction of rationals, field axioms, dedekind cut, lub, glb, completeness,
principle of induction, well ordering principle, countable and uncountable sets.
In this lecture prof Francis Su goes over an example that relates to the limit points of $Q$ in $R$. He goes on to say that any interval on real line contains rationals.

Question:
1.) Given the background is there a way to prove that every interval on $R$ contains $Q$ without using the density property of rational nos.

2.) How can we prove that the limit points of $Q$ is the whole of $R$ without using the density property

Comment: Your question 2 is more or less asking how can we prove that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: In my view, the statements 1. "Every real interval contains a rational number," 2. "The rational numbers are dense in the real numbers," and 3. "The set of limit points of the set of rational numbers in the set of real numbers is the set of real numbers" are essentially equivalent. If it matters, each can be deduced from little more than the Archimedean property ("for every real number $x$, there exists a natural number $n$ with $x < n$") and well-ordering of the natural numbers ("every non-empty set of natural numbers has a smallest element").

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang How can the well ordering principle help in this case?

Comment: In some standard sense , the definition of denseness of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is precisely that $A'=X$ . where $A'$ is the set of limit points of $X$.

Comment: One proof that every interval $(a, b)$ contains a rational is to pick a positive integer $q$ with $\frac{1}{q} < b - a$, and to consider the set $\frac{1}{q}\mathbf{Z}$ of integer multiples of $\frac{1}{q}$. More-or-less by the well-ordering property, there is a smallest integer $p + 1$ such that $b < \frac{p+1}{q}$. It follows wiht a bit of inequality manipulation that $a < \frac{p}{q} < b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every non empty open interval interval on $\mathbb{ R }$contains at least one $r\in\mathbb{Q }$.
2. Limit points of $\mathbb{ Q }$is the whole of $\mathbb{R }$.
3. For any $x\in \mathbb{R } $ there exists a sequence $(r_n) _{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ such that $(r_n) \to \mathbb{R}$.
4. Give any $x\in \mathbb{R }$ there exists a rational number $r$ such that $d(x, r)<\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon >0$
5. $\mathbb{Q }$ is dense in $\mathbb{R }$

All the above statements are equivalent.

> Question: 1) Given the background is there a way to prove that every
> interval on R contains Q without using the density property of
> rational nos.

> Question : 2) How can we prove that the limit points of Q is the whole of R
> without using the density property.

Your questions are equivalent to prove the density property of $\mathbb{Q }$ in $\mathbb{R}$.So "without density property " - this doesn't make sense. All are equivalent to density property.

But it is not difficult to prove $Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

I am going to prove using property $1)$ i.e any non-empty open interval contains at least one rational number. (In fact it contains infinitely many of them).

Choose an open interval $(a, b) \subset\mathbb{R } ,a<b $

Then, $\ell(a, b) =b-a>0$

Then by Archimedean Property, $\exists n\in {\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$\frac{1}{n}<(b-a) $$

$$\implies n(b-a) >1$$

Consider the open interval $(na, nb) $

And $$\ell(na, nb) >1$$

$\implies (na, nb) $ contains an integer. Because,

Consider, $$k=[na]=floor(na) $$

Then, $k\le na <k+1$ , $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Claim: $k+1<nb$

Suppose, $k+1\ge nb$

Then, $[na, nb]\subseteq [k, k+1]$

$\implies \ell[na, nb]\le \ell[k, k+1]$

$\implies n(b-a) \le 1$

But this contradict that $n(b-a) >1$.

Hence, $k+1<nb$
and set, $k+1=m$

And that implies $na<m<nb$

$\implies a< \frac{m}{n}<b$

Hence, $\frac{m}{n} \in (a, b) $ and $\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$

So we proved any non empty open interval contains a rational number.

Hence, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

And all equivalent conditions are satisfied.

Correct me if there is any mistake.

Hope it helps. Thanks.

{Edit: I want to share how to think about the proof .

Step 1 : Choose an open interval $(a, b) $.

And assume that it contains a rational number say $r$.

Then, $a<r<b$ and $r=\frac{m}{n} $ where$ m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n>0$.

Then, $a<\frac{m}{n}<b$

$\implies na<m<b$

Step 2: Now the the proof of existence of a rational number reduces to the proof of the existence of an integer.

Prove the result that any interval of length strictly larger than  $1 $ contains an integer. }

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I'm kind of new to the subject got a bit confused.

Comment: Step 1 : Choose an open interval $(a, b) $.

And assume that it contains a rational number say $r$.

Then, $a<r<b$ and $r=\frac{m}{n} $ where$ m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n>0$.

Then, $a<\frac{m}{n}<b$

$\implies na<m<b$\\

                                  Step 2: Now the the proof of existence of a rational number reduces to the proof of the existence of an integer. 

Prove the result that any interval of length strictly larger than  $1 $ contains an integer.

Comment: @grey Do you still have difficulty ?

Comment: No, I don't have difficulty now, thanks for the reply, I was actually saying in context to question that I got a bit confused your answer cleared my confusion.